# Dependency overriding in fastapi

Tags: python, dependency-injection, dependencies, fastapi

I read lots of Dependency overriding Questions in stack overflow and github discussion
But in my case overriding is not wokring? why?

my purpose :

for test_code I want to change original_db_url to test_db_url

for example
original_db_url : 111.111.1.1:54321
test_db_url : 222.222.2.2:54321

In normal case test_code reference test_db_url but still references original_db_url

I don't know what I missed !!!

OS : Mac os (m1 mac)
Docker : CentOs:7
python-version : 3.9.16
fastapi-version :0.95 ( I have tried fastapi-version 0.73,0.95 )

here is my code

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI,Depends,Request
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from routes.routes import apps
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from starlette.responses import FileResponse
from models.database import get_db
app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(get_db)])
app.mount("/static",StaticFiles(directory="static"),name = "static")
app.include_router(apps)
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")


origins = [
    "*"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


@app.get("/")
async def main(request:Request):
    return FileResponse("static/index.html")
```

routes/routes.py

```
# this is origina_db 
async def get_db():
    db = MongoClient("mongodb://111.111.1.1:54321/test")
    try:
        yield db.local
    finally:
        db.close()


@apps.post('/api/user',response_model = List[Return_User_type])
async def create_users(user: User,db = Depends(get_db)):
    user = dict(user)
    # hash 암호화
    user["password"] = pwd_context.hash(user["password"])
    db.user.insert_one(user)
    data = [db.user.find_one({"user_id":user["user_id"]})]
    serialize_objId(data)
    return JSONResponse(status_code = 202, content = data)
```

test_main.py

```
from .main import app
from routes.routes import apps
from pymongo import MongoClient
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from .models.database import get_db



async def override_get_db():
    db = MongoClient("mongodb://222.222.2.2:54254/test")
    try:
        yield db.local
    finally:
        db.close()
app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db
client = TestClient(app)
def test_read_main():
    response = client.get('/')
    assert  response.status_code == 200


def test_user_create():
    response = client.post('/api/user',headers = {'accept': 'application/json',
                                                         'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                           json = {
                               "name": "jae5yeon",
                               "user_id": "aavc1234",
                               "email": "kkg@naver.com",
                               "password": "12a3456",
                               "nickname": "user1r",
                               "disabled": "False"
                           }
                           )
    assert response.status_code == 202
```

I want to change Depends(get_db) to Depends(overrides_get_db) for test

Comment: Have you tried applying the override to `apps` instead of `app`. Haven't tested but my best guess is that overrides aren't shared with/between routers.

Comment: apps is API_router so apps.override~ raise AttributeError: 'APIRouter' object has no attribute 'dependency_overrides'

Comment: Usually you'd use an environment variable (for example through Pydantics Config base class) to override connection strings as they're not really dependencies per se; but whatever works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and the override works fine.
In your example, the `get_db` function is defined in 2 places: `models.database` and `routes.routes`. In my test I used only one `get_db` function.

Therefore:

- Check that the DB session dependency `get_db` you are using/importing is the same function for all your dependencies.
- There is no need to specify the DB session dependency in `app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(get_db)]`. In every view you will be applied  this dependence - each route will create a new session (even where it is not required). You have already identified the dependency of the DB session in the views that need it. See [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/global-dependencies/?h=fastapi%28depen#:%7E:text=In%20that%20case%2C%20they%20will%20be%20applied%20to%20all%20the%20path%20operations%20in%20the%20application%3A)